# Duplicating data (option) in a HTML select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `text box` that is used to search for `data` in a `database` (Order Number). The `data` returned (Products) is then added into a `select` as an `option`. The `data` is then removed from `select` when the user changes the `data` in the `text box`.

The functionality of this is somewhat working as I wanted, however I am having the `options` duplicated and not all of the `options` are removed.

I am unsure to where I am going wrong within the code, and would appreciate some guidance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#order_number').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var myCustomer = document.getElementById('customer');
        myCustomer.value = "";

        var mySelect = document.getElementById('product');
        var products_from_query = '';    

        var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

        // do nothing if it's an arrow key                    
        if (code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40) {
            return;
        }

        var keyword = $('#order_number').val();

        if (keyword.length) {
            $.ajax( {
                 url: '../stocks/order_search',
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: "keyword=" + keyword,
                 success: function(data) {
                     var length = mySelect.options.length;

                     for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                          mySelect.options[i] = null;
                     }

                     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                          newOption = document.createElement('option');

                          newOption.value = data[i]['ProductName'];

                          var options_seperator = ' - ';
                          var options_product_name = data[i]['ProductName'];
                          var options_product_description = data[i]['ProductDescription'];

                          var options_data = options_product_name.concat(options_seperator).concat(options_product_description);

                          if (typeof newOption.textContent === 'undefined') {

                              newOption.innerText = options_data;
                          } else {
                               newOption.textContent = options_data;
                          }

                          mySelect.appendChild(newOption);
                       };

                       myCustomer.value = data[0]['Customer'];
                 }                     

              })
          }                     

     });
 });
```

Comment: Where is **Java** in this ?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following one line before ajax call.

```
mySelect.html('');
```

Comment: I added this above `$.ajax` and get the following error: `mySelect.html is not a function`